# System Error C++

Tags: c++

So I'm making a script to make a txt file and put data on it, but when I run the system(); function, I get a strange error.  Here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string textFileName = "SavedPasswords.txt";
    string currentPassword = "Pas123!()";
    string currentName = "Home";
    string seperator = "====================";

    ofstream textFile(textFileName.c_str());

    textFile << "N: " << currentName << endl << "P: " << currentPassword << endl << endl << seperator << endl;

    string directory;
    size_t path = textFileName.rfind("\\");

    if(string::npos != path)
    {
        directory = textFileName.substr(0, path);
    }

    string systemCommands[3] = {"cd\\",
    "cd " + directory,
    "start " + textFileName};

    system(systemCommands[0]);
    system(systemCommands[1]);
    system(systemCommands[2]);
}
```

C:\Users\User\Desktop\SavePasswords\main.cpp|29|error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int system(const char*)'|

I get the same error for the next two lines.

Comment: Have you tried system(systemCommands[0].c_str()); ?

Comment: prefer `<cstdlib>` to `<stdlib.h>`

Comment: just googling for the error string gives you the answer immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> std::system ()

accepts only string with 'char *' type, which is different from 'std::string'. Try to use 'systemCommands[0].c_str()' This function member gets 'const char *' data from 'std::string' internals. Check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/).